# Bash command not found rvm at startup, Mint

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, rvm, linux-mint

Whenever I open the terminal in linux mint 17 I get:

```
No command 'Usage' found, did you mean:
 Command 'osage' from package 'graphviz' (main)
Usage: command not found
rvm-installer: command not found
Options: command not found
bash: /home/XXX/.bashrc: line 59: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: /home/XXX/.bashrc: line 59: `  [[--]version] <version>'
```

I installed ruby yesterday and reinstalled it (following the website), but that didn't helped.

Added the .bashrc file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4srudgpjo4hok9/.bashrc?dl=0

And an image for the lines (with 59) regarding ruby. [image: .bashrc rvm]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your .bashrc file. When your terminal opens normally (as a [non-login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)), it uses the configurations specified in the .bashrc file. It appears the content of the .bashrc file has been modified due to you installing ruby. Maybe you edited the file manually? Could you update your question including the contents of the .bashrc file? I will update my answer accordingly when you do.

**Edit:**
Instead of taking a screenshot you could have copied the content of the `.bashrc` file and paste it in the stackoverflow text field. Could you do that? It will show the entire content of the file.

From what I can see though in the editor image, none of the content in the file should be there. It seems somehow you managed to pipe the output of running the ruby-installer executable without parameters to your `.bashrc` file, populating it with content which causes it to give those errors.

I see a possible solution but before I post anything lets see everything in your .bashrc file first.

**Solution:**
To solve, first remove everything between 
`source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`. That content is outputed from running the ruby-installer executable on the terminal without arguments. Somehow you got it in your .bashrc, by cut and paste maybe.

Next, you have `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` twice. Remove one of them. Everything else looks fine otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for helping, added the file to the original post.

Comment: You want only the lines consurning rvm as text?
There is more underneath, I saw later it's in total 70 lines.
With the image I included the file itself as dropbox file.
I can post the text if you want.

Shall I delete the lines consuring rvm completely then?

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear as day; in your `.bashrc` file:

```
bash: /home/XXX/.bashrc: line 59: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: /home/XXX/.bashrc: line 59: `  [[--]version] <version>'
```

Obviously you've got to fix that `line 59`.